# One dimension cellular automation in Python

Tags: python, state-machine

Here is my implementation for one dimensional cellular automation in Python. Any suggestions for more efficiency - other strategies?

```
ncells = ['111','110','101','100','011','010','001','000']

def next_state (state, rule):
    newstate = ''
    binrule = bin(rule)[2:]
    binrule = (8-len(binrule))*'0' + binrule
    for i in range(len(state)):
        cells = state[i-1] + state[i] + state[(i+1)%len(state)]
        newstate += binrule[ncells.index(cells)]
    return newstate

def wolfram (init_state, generations, rule):
    state = init_state
    for i in range(generations):
        yield state 
        state = next_state(state, rule)

for i in wolfram('000000000010000000000', 30, 30):
    print i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Instead of

  ```
  binrule = bin(rule)[2:]
  binrule = (8-len(binrule))*'0' + binrule
  ```

  you can use string formatting:

  ```
  binrule = '{:08b}'.format(rule)
  ```
- Let the caller compute `binrule` so this only gets done once.
- Better yet, precompute a transition table: a dictionary that maps cell triplets directly to the new values.

  ```
  transitions = dict(zip(ncells, binrule))
  ```
- Slightly more convenient than this

  ```
  for i in range(len(state)):
      cells = state[i-1] + state[i] + state[(i+1)%len(state)]
  ```

  is this:

  ```
  padded_state = state[-1] + state + state[0]
  for i in range(len(state)):
      cells = padded_state[i:i+3]
  ```

Putting it all together:

```
NCELLS = ['111','110','101','100','011','010','001','000']

def next_state(state, transition_table):
    padded_state = state[-1] + state + state[0]
    triplets = [padded_state[i:i+3] for i in range(len(state))]
    newstate = ''.join(transition_table[cells] for cells in triplets)
    return newstate

def wolfram(init_state, generations, rule):
    state = init_state
    binrule = '{:08b}'.format(rule)
    transitions = dict(zip(NCELLS, binrule))
    for i in range(generations):
        yield state 
        state = next_state(state, transitions)

for i in wolfram('000000000010000000000', 30, 30):
    print i
```

Answer (score 2):

`ncells.index(cells)` is linear. You could treat `cells` as a binary number and use it as an index in a `code` array. Not sure whether the access in constant time compensates the cost of the conversion with an 8-rule though.